# Fetching a single post along with all comments relating to that post in Asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello Everyone,
             I am facing a problem presently with a query that uses the id parameter in the query string to fetch a single post from the database and also retrieve all comments that belong to the posts. So far   i know that i want a single post hence my view will not contain the IEnumerable interface because in my query i use .single(). However since i'm fetching a list of comments from the database and not just one comment i know that will be IEnumerable. My problem is how to combine both interfaces so that i can display that single post and all comments that belong to it .

```
 public class ReadPostsVM
{
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }

    public string PostContent { get; set; }

    public string PostAuthor { get; set; }

    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public string CommentAuthor { get; set; }

    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }


}
```

This is what i tried in the controller

```
public ActionResult ReadPost(int id)
{
    var query = from p in db.Posts.Where(p => p.PostId == id)
                from c in db.Replies.Where(c => c.PostId == id)
                join u in db.UserProfiles
                on p.AuthorId equals u.UserId
                where p.PostId == id
                select new ReadPostsVM()
                {
                    PostTitle = p.PostTitle,
                    PostContent = p.PostContent,
                    PostDate = p.DateCreated,
                    PostAuthor = u.UserName,
                    Comment = c.Reply1,
                    CommentAuthor = u.UserName,
                    CommentDate = c.ReplyDate
                };

    var query = from p in db.Posts
                join u in db.UserProfiles
                on p.AuthorId equals u.UserId
                where p.PostId == id
                select new ReadPostsVM()
                {
                    PostTitle = p.PostTitle,
                    PostContent = p.PostContent,
                    PostDate = p.DateCreated,
                    PostAuthor = u.UserName,

                };

    return View(query.Single());


}
```

However in the view i have

```
@model IEnumerable<Blogger.ViewModels.ReadPostsVM>
```

and a foreach loop which gave me an error saying

```
Sequence does not contain any element
```

Another option i think i have is to fetch just this below

```
public ActionResult ReadPost(int id)
    {

        var query = from p in db.Posts
                    join u in db.UserProfiles
                    on p.AuthorId equals u.UserId
                    where p.PostId == id
                    select new ReadPostsVM()
                    {
                        PostTitle = p.PostTitle,
                        PostContent = p.PostContent,
                        PostDate = p.DateCreated,
                        PostAuthor = u.UserName,

                    };

        return View(query.Single());


    }
```

to get that single post using to return just a single post and maybe i can then use a Partial view to display the comments.

```
@model Blogger.ViewModels.ReadPostsVM
```

Please help me  out how can I achieve this aim. If i am to use a partial view how can i make that partial view to fetch comments based on the parameter in the url since i will have to invoke an action with an id parameter but i dont have any link pointing to that page and also i dont think it would make sense like that. I hope my question makes sense? Please help!

To show the relationship between the Posts entity and the comments entity i have added the Posts.cs class and Replies.cs class below

```
public partial class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        this.Replies = new HashSet<Reply>();
    }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reply> Replies { get; set; }
}



 public partial class Reply
    {
        public int ReplyId { get; set; }
        public string Reply1 { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ReplyDate { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you use LINQ to simplify queries. Once you have set the one-to-many relationship up correctly, it will be straightforward to display related comments.
For example using Razor syntax in your view:
 @foreach (var item in Model.comments)
        {
// display comment content
}
where the model is your post.

Comment: How is Post (entity) class look like? Does it have one to many relationship with Comment entity?

Comment: There is no need to use a partial view to display the comments, although this can help to keep your code tidy. This gives a quick overview of setting up a one-to-many: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927018/asp-net-mvc-4-one-to-many-relationship-article-tags

Comment: @Sam The Post entity has a one to many relationship with the Comment entity. I have updated my question above.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully me brief answer helps. The main issue seems to be that your ReadPostsVM only has a link to a single comment instead of a list of comments, which you need in order to loop through them.

Comment: By the way, the single means make sure that I return just one post. This does not mean that you can't return multiple comments with it.

Comment: @Sam i tried using 'public IEnumerable<comment> comments { get; set; }' but while mapping in the controller like this  'Comments = c.Reply1', there was an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Blogger.Models.Reply>'.

Comment: Reply1 is a string and you want to map the set of comments. I'm not sure why you are looking to map comment replies to be the set of comments - you want to map post comments to the set of comments.

Comment: @Sam honestly i'm lost again. Can you help with a code rewrite? and hope i'm not confusing you cause i used "reply" instead of comment. That should be grammar error but i still mean comments

Comment: So replies are the same as comments? In which case, why not try the code below, but with: 
PostComments = p.Replies 
or better yet: PostReplies = p.Replies

Comment: Apologies I did not have time to do a code rewrite. I'm glad that you found someone that did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your view models so that the Post view model contains a collection of Comments

View models

```
public class CommentVM
{
  public string Comment { get; set; }
  public string CommentAuthor { get; set; }
  public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
}

public class PostVM
{
  public string PostTitle { get; set; }
  public string PostContent { get; set; }
  public string PostAuthor { get; set; }
  public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
  List<CommentVM> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Controller (I'll leave it to you covert to LINQ To SQL)

```
public ActionResult ReadPost(int id)
{
  Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
  PostVM model = new PostVM()
  {
    PostTitle = post.PostTitle,
    PostContent = post.PostContent,
    PostAuthor = post.UserProfile.UserName,
    PostDate = post.DateCreated,
    Comments = post.Replies.Select(r => new CommentVM()
    {
      Comment = r.Reply1,
      CommentAuthor = r.UserProfile.UserName,
      CommentDate = r.ReplyDate
    })
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model PostVM
...
@DisplayFor(m => m.PostTitle)
...
@DisplayFor(m => m.PostDate )

@foreach(var comment in Model.Comments)
{
  @DisplayFor(comment.Comment)
  ...
  @DisplayFor(comment.CommentDate)
}
```

Comment: I never knew i could mix viewmodels like that, God bless you so much, I called on you and you heeded. would try the above solution and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like automapper to simplify your mappings. Otherwise, to keep things simple, in your viewmodel have something like:

```
public IEnumerable<comment> comments { get; set; }
```

and then have a method that populates this correctly:

```
 select new ReadPostsVM()
                    {
                        PostTitle = p.PostTitle,
                        PostContent = p.PostContent,
                        PostDate = p.DateCreated,
                        PostAuthor = u.UserName,
                        PostReplies = p.Replies
                    };
```

You will then be able to access the reply info in your view by looping through the PostReplies:

```
@foreach (var reply in Model.PostReplies)
 {
<div>reply.Reply1</div>
<div>reply.UserProfile.name</div>
}
```

Comment: but that will fetch just the comments and not other properties in the viewModel such as the CommentAuthor and the CommentDate.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. You should be able to loop through PostComments, using razor for example and then get to the other properties. 
Perhaps, if you have lazy-loading turned on, then you need something like: PostComments = p.comments.Include(CommentAuthor)